# Angular 2 - Sublist loop to a select html element

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects like this.

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Name 1'
  children: [
     {
       id: 2,
       name: 'Name 2'
     }
  ]
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Name 3'
  children: [
     {
       id: 4,
       name: 'Name 4'
     }
  ]
}
```

Now i need to make all of them options to a select element.

If I make

```
<option *ngFor="let element of elements" value="{{element.id}}">― {{element.name}}</option>
```

It will show only "Name 1" and "Name 3". How should I make the loop to include all the elements

I don't want to use an array with 4 items. I'm trying to find a way without the need of change the array

"Name 1", "Name 2", "Name3", "Name 4"

Thank you

Comment: Use an array with 4 items in it?

Comment: That's the point... I don't want to use an array with 4 items. I'm trying to find a way without the need of change the array

Comment: So include that information in the question, people can't know if you don't explicitly mention it.

Comment: i add it. any suggestions for the loop?

Comment: What are the rules for generating the select options? are all the properties random or what? Include that information as well in the question...

Comment: No the properties ane not random. "id", "name", "children"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You can leverage `ngForTemplate` to achieve desired result:

```
<select>
  <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="elements" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"></ng-template>
  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-element>
    <option value="{{element.id}}">― {{element.name}}</option>
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="element.children" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"></ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</select>
```

It should work for any level of sub elements

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/u1Tll6tk3DkL6sQdygmZ?p=preview)**

2) Another way might be using custom pipe like:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'flatten'
})
export class FlattenPipe {
  transform(arr: any[], property: string) {
    if(!arr) return [];
    return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return [...acc, cur, ...this.transform(cur[property], property)];
    }, [])
  }
}
```

and in html

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let element of elements | flatten: 'children'" value="{{element.id}}">― {{element.name}}</option>
</select>
```

It should also work for any level of sub elements

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SZE0LuV3Tx4Kyd44iD2O)**

Comment: What if i want to add children to a children? (unlimited)

Comment: Nice... one and final question... If you can see I use a dash before the name  "―". What if I want to put two or three or four (etc) dashes before the label depending the depth of the children?

Comment: You are my god of javascript