# Angular 2 Render Flat List from Hierarchal Data

Tags: angular, ngfor

Working within **Angular 2**, I have the following data:

```
let nodes = {
  name: 'ABC Product',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'XYZ Product',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'GHI Product',
          children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF Product',
      children: []
    },
  ]
}
```

(the real data has a lot more fields)

I need to render all products in one flat list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Level 1: ABC Product</li>
  <li>Level 2: DEF Product</li>
  <li>Level 2: XYZ Product</li>
  <li>Level 3: GHI Product</li>
</ul>
```

Please bear in mind that each level needs to sorted by `name`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why can't you flatten your `nodes` and create a flat data structure?

Comment: i have no control over the format of what webservice is returning to me, or do you mean flatten it in JS and then parse it?

Comment: sure, in JS in your application code

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/NOxFxbKDjKHtdtURnP8r?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui that's fantastic! I'd like to accept this answer, but it's only a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare data before rendering like:

```
function flatten(arr: any[], property: string, childrenProperty: string, level: number = 1, dict: any = {}) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    dict[level] = [...dict[level] || [], { level, data: cur.name }];
    flatten(cur[childrenProperty], property, childrenProperty, level + 1, dict)
    return dict;
  }, dict);
}

...
export class AppComponent {
  nodes = {
    name: 'ABC Product',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'XYZ Product',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'GHI Product',
            children: []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'DEF Product',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  };

  flattenNodes: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    let dict = flatten([this.nodes], 'name', 'children');
    this.flattenNodes = Object.keys(dict).sort((a: any, b: any) => a - b).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return [...acc, ...dict[cur].sort((a, b) => (a.data < b.data) ? -1 : (a.data > b.data) ? 1 : 0)];
    }, [])
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NOxFxbKDjKHtdtURnP8r?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular 2 - Sublist loop to a select html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860962/angular-2-sublist-loop-to-a-select-html-element/43861196#43861196)